# Locate columns in dataframe to graph

Tags: excel, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have an excel file with 3 columns and 60 rows. The first column is the Date but I want to put that on the x axis and plot the other 2 against it. I need help locating the 2 other columns so i can enter it in ax1.plot() and ax2.plot().

I have tried to locate it by [:,1] but that doesnt work and I have tried to locate it by the name of the column. The second column is "S&P/TSX Composite index (^GSPTSE)" and the third column is "Bitcoin CAD (BTC-CAD)"

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


InputData = pd.read_excel('Python_assignment_InputData.xlsx')

#InputData = InputData[:15]
"""
print("a)\n", InputData,"\n")
print("b)")
InputData['Date'] = InputData.DATE.dt.year
InputData['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(InputData.Date).dt.year

"""
#ax1 = InputData.iloc[:,1]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot()
ax2.plot()
ax1.set_ylabel("TSX", color = 'b')
ax2.set_ylabel("BTC", color = 'g')
ax1.set_xlabel("Year")
plt.title("Question 6")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the print output of `InputData.columns`?

Comment: print `InputData`, and see your columns name

Comment: Index(['Date', 'S&P/TSX Composite index (^GSPTSE)', 'Bitcoin CAD (BTC-CAD)'], dtype='object') @OluwafemiSule